# Suggestion for handling duplicate questions

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

When I find a question that has a notice telling me it was marked as a duplicate (and closed), it would really help if the notice included a link to that duplicate. I may have something to add, and I can't find a reasonable duplicate that's open for new answers. I may also find a better answer on the duplicate page. I usually can't find the duplicate.

Is there a simple way to find a duplicate that I'm missing?

Comment: Someone mentioned this a few days ago, as well.  Did the link in the banner of closed questions pointing to the original question suddenly disappear?

Comment: See the banner (that's colored the same as the box around your user name and avatar) at the top of every closed question. It contains the link to one or more duplicate questions.

Comment: Can you link to the post that you are referring to? A random duplicate post like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564497/how-can-i-convince-ie-to-honor-my-explicit-instructions-to-make-a-table-column-x) shows there's a message on top that does just that.